# How to use number of CPUs as a multiplier in monit config?

Tags: monitoring, monit, system-monitoring

What is the best way to use number of CPUs as a multiplier in monit confs? I need this for a system that has varrying number of CPUs, depending on predicted load.

Right now the only idea I have is using **sed** or some other program to alter the config file.

This is something I would like to do:

```
check system MySystem
    if loadavg (5min) > 0.8 * NUMBER_OF_CPUS then alert
```

Comment: Depending on the number of CPUs you have .8 may alert too early.

Comment: It was just an example and number out of my head and has nothing to do with the problem.